# validate number without notation (scientific)

Tags: php, validation, numbers, scientific-notation

I have a real problem in the validation of numbers.

If my form has a field for a monetary value (1.99), i can use floatval to validate the input and save in my DB.

But if the value is in scientific notation (1E7) the operation will return true and I will have problems with save in my DB.

I'm days trying to solve this problem, how can I get around this? 
thanks in advance

example:

```
floatval( '17E20' ) // float(1.7E+21)
floatval( '0xFF'  ) // float(0)
floatval( '7E-10' ) // float(7.0E-10)
floatval( '1.23X' ) // float(1.23)
```

Comment: `floatval` is not validation function. You could use regular expression for this.

Comment: I know, the function would is_float

Comment: No, `is_float` is not user input validation function. It's just check type of variable. :^ ) Do you have anything against the regular expressions?

Comment: i not work well with numeric types, so do not know what the best rule for the case. u can help? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User input from browser is string. We need validate string as simple decimal fraction notation with 2 digits after `.` or `,`.

```
$value = '122.33';
$result = preg_match('/^\d+([\.,]\d{1,2})?$/', $value);
                               // ^ one or two digit
                           // ^ dot or comma
                      // ^ at least one digit
```

Comment: The 'is_numeric' function is very flexible in accepting scientific notation. Has not native function to check numbers 0-9 monetary and integer? I plan on using your RE with other rules and create a function `TypeInput` like validation to return with int, float, string ... think a good idea? Thanks for RE

Comment: @PapaCharlie , yes, abstraction is proper orientation to go.

Comment: I will use the ER to check the type to facilitate the work. Thank you for your help

Comment: if I correctly create a function to return me the type of input, i can do something like: `if(typeof($input, 'float')) (float)$input`, so i'm changing `string to float` without risk the scientific notation operate an exponent. am I correct?

Comment: @PapaCharlie , it's risk to work with money using float field.

Comment: Thank you, I will exhaust tests